# Image Height auto resize to fit its content in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Image control to show the photo that pick up from Gallery or take from Camera.
There are 2 types of orientation as you know, Portrait and Landscape.
Width of Image control is fixed.

```
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" or WidthRequest="200"
```

But I want to change automatically height of Image control to fit and show fully the photo.

Is there any way to do this in XAML or C#?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you see the [Aspect](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Image.Aspect/) property?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Sure, I've tried AspectFit and AspectFill, and other ones. But it seems not to change Image control size automatically. Which one do you want me to try with Aspect?

Comment: Ah sorry, I got you wrong. I don't think there is a built-in property that will resize the view for you automatically. You probably need to implement logic to get the height of your image and size the control to that yourself.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I am getting photo using Xam.Plugin.Media but it doesn't return the image metadata to get image size. any suggestion for it?

Comment: Have you tried using FFImageLoading ? It's almost become a standard when displaying images in Xamarin.Forms